# Wordpress - rewrite "title_reply" to "title_reply_to" using javascript

Tags: wordpress

I am using standard "comment-reply.js" to move comment form below replied comment. It works ok in my custom theme. I need only one thing: rewrite "title_reply" to "title_reply_to".

My default "title_reply" is "Ask your question". When user click "reply button", I need to rewrite "Ask yout question" to "Your reply to %s".

I tried to place

```
$("#reply-title").text("Your reply to %s")
```

within "comment-reply.js", but with no luck.

Edit: here is code generated by Wordpress:

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Ask yout question: <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/lekarna_u_hygie/poradny/%e2%80%a2-on-line-poradna/#respond" style="">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>
```

Notice part "Ask yout question", that I want rewrite to "Your reply to %s".

And here si standard "comment-reply.js" which comes with Wordpress:

```
addComment = {
    moveForm : function(commId, parentId, respondId, postId) {
        var t = this, div, comm = t.I(commId), respond = t.I(respondId), cancel = t.I('cancel-comment-reply-link'), parent = t.I('comment_parent'), post = t.I('comment_post_ID');

        if ( ! comm || ! respond || ! cancel || ! parent )
            return;

        t.respondId = respondId;
        postId = postId || false;

        if ( ! t.I('wp-temp-form-div') ) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = 'wp-temp-form-div';
            div.style.display = 'none';
            respond.parentNode.insertBefore(div, respond);
        }

        comm.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, comm.nextSibling);
        if ( post && postId )
            post.value = postId;
        parent.value = parentId;
        cancel.style.display = '';

        cancel.onclick = function() {
            var t = addComment, temp = t.I('wp-temp-form-div'), respond = t.I(t.respondId);

            if ( ! temp || ! respond )
                return;

            t.I('comment_parent').value = '0';
            temp.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, temp);
            temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
            this.style.display = 'none';
            this.onclick = null;
            return false;
        }

        try { t.I('comment').focus(); }
        catch(e) {}

        return false;
    },

    I : function(e) {
        return document.getElementById(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `title_reply` and `reply-title` don't match. Post more code perhaps?

Comment: "title_reply"and "title_reply_to" are only descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this problem by adding two lines of code to the original JavaScript file.

This is what the js file looks like now:

```
var addComment = {
    moveForm : function(commId, parentId, respondId, postId) {
        var t = this, div, comm = t.I(commId), respond = t.I(respondId), cancel = t.I('cancel-comment-reply-link'), parent = t.I('comment_parent'), post = t.I('comment_post_ID');

        if ( ! comm || ! respond || ! cancel || ! parent )
            return;

        t.respondId = respondId;
        postId = postId || false;

        if ( ! t.I('wp-temp-form-div') ) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = 'wp-temp-form-div';
            div.style.display = 'none';
            respond.parentNode.insertBefore(div, respond);
        }

        comm.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, comm.nextSibling);
        if ( post && postId )
            post.value = postId;
        parent.value = parentId;
        cancel.style.display = '';
        // Added.
        jQuery('#reply-title').contents()[0].textContent = "Respond";

        cancel.onclick = function() {
            var t = addComment, temp = t.I('wp-temp-form-div'), respond = t.I(t.respondId);

            if ( ! temp || ! respond )
                return;

            t.I('comment_parent').value = '0';
            temp.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, temp);
            temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
            this.style.display = 'none';
            this.onclick = null;
            // Added
            jQuery('#reply-title').contents()[0].textContent = "Leave a Reply";
            return false;
        };

        try { t.I('comment').focus(); }
        catch(e) {}

        return false;
    },

    I : function(e) {
        return document.getElementById(e);
    }
};
```

When you click reply link, the title changes to 'Respond'; when you cancel the reply, it changes back to 'Leave a Reply'.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution without changing Wordpress core files.
First change comment form default title to:

```
$default['title_reply'] = __( '<span class="title-text">Leave a comment</span>' );
```

and reply cancel link to:

```
$default['cancel_reply_link'] = __( '<span class="close-comment">Cancel reply</span>' );
```

add some jQuery:

```
$('.comment-reply-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.comment-reply-title .title-text').html('Reply to comment')
})
$('.close-comment').on('click', function(){
    $('.comment-reply-title .title-text').html('Leave a comment')
})
```

test it and give yourself a high-five!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried @Wally code on WP 5.2.2 and it needed a bit of fixing. Here is what worked in my case:

```
$('.comment-reply-link').on('click', function () {
        // get old title
        let old_text = $('#reply-title').html();
        // split by title and 'cancel reply' link
        let splited = old_text.split(/<small>(.*?)<\/small>/);
        // add the new title in span (for styling purposes)
        let replyTo = `<span class="replay-to-text">${$(this).attr('aria-label')}</span>`;
        let newText = old_text.replace(splited[0], replyTo);
        $('#reply-title').html(newText);
        // add this line if the 'cansel reply' link is hidden
        $('#cancel-comment-reply-link').show();
    })
```

The replay-to text is held in attribute of the "reply" link called `aria-label`. So I basically just replace the title part from the original comment title. Also I use this regex as the "cancel replay" text was in the same html element as the title so I had to preserve it as the replace would also remove it.

I wouldn't say that this is the rigth way to do this. In the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) it is clearly stated that there is attribute `title_reply_to` that should handle this but it didn't work in my case (I guess theme problem). So consider the above code a hacky trick then the standard way the things are working.